# Wait until resource is available?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a good way to do this code, (to wait until this file is unlocked) when I get:

**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process**

I'm working on a web app so I can have concurrent access to this file from several different applications.

```
bool isLock = false;
do
{
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, value, Encoding.Unicode);
        isLock = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        Thread.Sleep(30);
        isLock = true;
    }    
}while (isLock);
```

Comment: Can you not take a temporary copy of the file for each concurrent user to access?

Comment: make use of : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6897bc/understanding-and-using-msmq/ might resolve your issue

Comment: The good way is not using files in a shared environment, exactly because of issues like this. Can't you write to a database?

Comment: What else is accessing the document? It's most likely that you didn't close your connection the last time that your accessed the file and that you are the one with the open connection to it.

Comment: @krillgar yes I close the connection but it is not the probleme I close and I dispose the connection, but when the file is used... is used

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush I guess I can

Comment: You could create a named event to allow you to synchronize access between your applications.  That doesn't handle every case, but it should make the common ones much more efficient.  See [Interprocess Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684123(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @CodeCaster database will not avoid my waiting problem

Comment: That loop is going to be interesting if the path is invalid or the disk is full...

Comment: Try catching a more specific condition. You're ignoring all other errors right now (and would loop indefinitely).

Comment: @MatthewWatson I understand what you mean but I can filter those kind of exception, and It well because this code stink I ask how can I do what I want in a different way

Comment: @ChristopheDebove Setting `isLock = false;` means execution will never get into the `while` loop in the first place.

Comment: @usr as I said to Matthew I'm agree with your point of view

Comment: @HABO I cannot deal with other app

Comment: @RoadieRich I fixed this issue

Comment: @ChristopheDebove, `database will not avoid my waiting problem`. Now that statement is dead wrong. Databases handle locking. The default for almost all database engines is optimistic locking. And it's all done automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lock variable is of no use when multiple applications are in the scenario.

Rather test if you can File.OpenWrite and then write to the file.
If you cannot access the file loop and wait or write to a temporary file and start another thread looping and waiting until the temporary file can be merged.

Maybe even better would be to store immediatley to temp and let a watchdog write to your storage file.

```
public void SomeWhereInYourWebServerApplication
    {           
        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher("tempfolder");
        fsw.Created += fsw_Created;

        // save new entries to tempfolder
    }

    void fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("tempfolder"))
        {
         try
           {
            string fileText = File.ReadAllText(file);
            File.AppendAllText("myStorage.txt", fileText);
            File.Delete(file);
           }
          catch
           {
              // for me it's ok when we try to append the file the next time
              // something new is coming
           }
        }
    }
```

Nice and simple as i think.

Don't forget to do proper exception handling when files are involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely *must* do it this way, and you have no control over the apps that are using the file, then your code is almost there.

It just needs to be made slightly more robust:

```
public static bool TryWriteText(string path, string text, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    Contract.Requires(path != null); // Or replace with: if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    Contract.Requires(text != null); // Or replace with: if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    while (stopwatch.Elapsed < timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, text);
            return true;
        }

        catch (IOException){} // Ignore IOExceptions until we time out, then return false.

        Thread.Sleep(100); // 100ms is rather short - it could easily be 1000 I think.
    }                      // Perhaps this should be passed in as a parameter.

    return false;
}
```

Alternative version that rethrows the last `IOException` on timeout (this is arguably better since you don't hide all the exceptions):

```
public static void TryWriteText(string path, string text, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    Contract.Requires(path != null); // Or replace with: if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    Contract.Requires(text != null); // Or replace with: if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, text);
        }

        catch (IOException)
        {
            if (stopwatch.Elapsed > timeout)
                throw;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

But you should only use such code as a last resort.